# How to display image in child window? : Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-asynctask, android-inflate

I an having list view of Image and i want something like...when user long press on item it fetches image asynchronously and display it in child-Window
i want to know... how can i handle **onPostExecute(Bitmap result)** event
any idea...

Thank you

Comment: what you want? you want to ask for what to write in onPostExecute or when to call it?

Comment: i want to know... how can i have child window after image download complete...and i want to show image in it...any idea?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean by child-window or exactly what you are asking. I am assuming you want to put the image into the child window. You could pass the reference of this child-window to the AsyncTask and then you could handle it on your postExecute event

Comment: basically i want to have child window like a pop-up and display image in it... i had tried by having image.xml file and inflate that but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... did it using Custom Dialog 
and gave reference of it in AsyncTask class